# How to catch custom java8 exception from react?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, java-8, axios

Following code generates exception as UserAlreadyExist.

```
Optional<User> userCheck = userRepository.findByUsername(createRequest.getUsername());
    if(StringUtils.hasText(userCheck.get().getUsername())){
        String errorMessage = "User already exist: "+ userCheck.get().getUsername();
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException(errorMessage);
    }
```

When i try to get error message from my react app with these codes i only get Internal server error message. My header contains header token and application/JSON header.

```
export const createUserService = (data) => {
return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(USERS_BASE, data, getHeaderWithToken())
        .then(function (response) {
            resolve(response);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)//returns "Internal Server Error" message
        console.log(error.response) // returns object with empty message field and other parameters.
            reject(error)
    })
}));
```

};

How can i get the error message i sent like

```
String errorMessage = "User already exist: "+ userCheck.get().getUsername();
        throw new UserAlreadyExistException(errorMessage);
```

this is my UserAlreadyExistException class btw.

```
public class UserAlreadyExistException extends RuntimeException {
public UserAlreadyExistException(String message) {
    super(message);
    
}}
```

Comment: You can take a look at @restControllerAdvice usage. You can return meaningful response to front end

Comment: Gonna take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return custom Response with @RestControllerAdvice for the custom exception you are throwing.
Please check the example below.

```
 @RestControllerAdvice
    public class ControllerExceptionHandler {
      
  @ExceptionHandler(value = {UserAlreadyExistException.class})
  @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public ErrorMessage userAlreadyExistException(UserAlreadyExistException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorMessage message = new ErrorMessage(
        status,
        date,
        ex.getMessage(),
        description);
    
    return message;
  }
}
```

It will be much easier for you to see the error in your Frontent application with a Response that you will return like this.

Comment: With similar structure i made the code work, dearly thanks! Now i need to understand it :D

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! I would be very happy if you accept my answer.